# Count word appear in csv

Tags: python

I have a plain csv file that starts with these 2 rows:

```
1.Clubhouse,Fibre Ready,.......
2.Clubhouse,Aircon,.........
3....
```

I want use python to write out a program that count how many times each column appear in csv file  . I have tried several ways but it did not work out.

My output should be like this:

```
Clubhouse: .... times
Fibre Ready: .... times
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv

counter = Counter()
with open('furniture.csv') as fobj:
    reader = csv.reader(fobj)
    for row in reader:
        counter.update(row)

for k, v in counter.items():
    print('{}: {} times'.format(k, v))
```

Output for your two lines:

```
Clubhouse: 2 times
Fibre Ready: 1 times
Fitness Corner: 2 times
Aircon: 2 times
...
```

You can also access single items::

```
>>> counter['Clubhouse']
2
>>> counter['Fibre Ready']
1
```

`collections.Counter` is useful for this type of tasks:

> Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
>   or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
>   are stored as dictionary values.